# Delegating Constructors

Tags: c++

I am learning about Delegating Constructors.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A(int i, int j): num1(i), num2(j){
        average=(num1+num2)/2;
    }
    A(): A(0){   }
    A(int i): A(i, 0){  }

private:
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int average;
};
```

and this is what I succeed to understend. I don't know such it works in a int main().

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: yes you are right! i want an exemple about this it works in int main , so how i can initialize by exemple A a object.

Comment: This code should not compile, `<< endl;` is not valid.

Comment: @alin, The same way as if you weren't using delegating constructors.

Comment: @Borgleader without endl

Comment: when I do this A a() by exemple, i recive a lot of errors

Comment: @alin A a() is most likely MVP. What about A a;?

Comment: @Borgleader you were right, the problem was this endl;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need just an example to how to create objects from `A`:

```
int main()
{
  A obj1(10, 20); // Calls A(10, 20)                average: 15
  A obj2;         // Calls A() -> A(0) ->  A(0, 0)  average: 0
  A obj3(100);    // Calls A(100) -> A(100, 0)      average: 50
}
```

Comment: yes, i resolved the problem, thank you, i think that the problem were <<endl :))